# Gtkmm TreeView: Accessing dynamically added columns

Tags: c++, treeview, gtkmm

I'm currently doing this to add `numCols` columns to a TreeView (`ColumnRecord columns`):

```
Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring>* c;
for( int i = 0; i < numCols; i++ ) {
    c = new Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring>();
    columns.add(*c);
    list.append_column(titles[i], *c);
    iss.clear();
}
```

To get an element at a certain row and column with a preset ColumnRecord, I would do something like `Gtk::TreeModel::Row row; row[columns.c1] = blah`. Now that the columns aren't named however, how will I access them?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a potential memory leak here.  You are `newing` up a `TreeModelColumn` with what looks like no way to ever `delete` it.  With a widget that lasts the life time of the GUI this may not be a big deal.  Another option is to use gtkmm's [manage](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-memory-widgets.html.en#memory-managed-widgets) capabilities and let it worry about the memory.

Second, to address your problem, the way I've handled this scenario in the past was to collect my `TreeModelColumn` pointers into a `std::vector` or `std::map` so I access them later.